# How about embedding this live blitz feed to the site?

Tags: feature-request

According to a [recent announcement by Chessbase](http://en.chessbase.com/post/bring-live-chess-action-to-your-web-site), it is as easy as

```
<iframe src="http://liveblitz.chessbase.com" width="360" height ="360"></iframe>
```

So perhaps it is a good idea to embed this on the Chess SE site?

Comment: Any moving things on the browser window are distracting, and I don't feel like advertising Playchess or any other site here for free, so I'd say no.